# Is the Magen HaElef Sefaradi or Ashkenazi?

Tags: jewish-books, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi

There is a Sefer written by someone named Yaakov Ben Yaakov Moshe called Magen HaElef. Is he Sefaradi or Ashekneazi?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_of_Lissa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [cover page](http://hebrewbooks.org/9151) says that he was from [ליסא](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%90) (modern-day [Leszno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leszno)) which makes him Ashkenazi.

Comment: @Vram It's in Poland. GershonGold feel free to adjust/revert my edits.